# Elasticsearch Aggregation size=0. Default settings tweak

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I was working on elasticsearch and came to a point where I have 120 hits. But elastic search by default returns top 10 hits. Since then, every time I write an aggregation, I kept on giving "size=0". Is there a way where we can do this globally and applies to every query I write? I want to make change the settings of elasticsearch to make its defalut size to unlimited. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: searched many websites and blogs with out any luck.

Comment: "https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/4838" and "https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1776" this gives an answer to add size=0 but not how to change the default setting.